(Android Studio Tests) Error: Could not find or load main class Files\NVIDIA
I'm developing an application in Android Studio for Windows.
When attempting to run one of the JUnit4 tests I've created, I get this error:
> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\NVIDIA
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\NVIDIA
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 18' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 1s

I'm assuming that this error has to do with Java being passed in an argument for C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation or C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Tools and incorrrectly handling it. But I'm unsure where or how to fix it?
Running the exact same test on MacOS works as expected.

It does look like a configuration issue with the project, but I'm not sure what it might be.  Try looking in the project files for "NVIDIA" or "Files\NVIDIA" and see where this string might be coming from.  Just to confirm -- this is a project created with Android Studio and you've tried running from inside Android Studio?

I've check and there's no files anywhere in my project folder that reference ‘Files/NVIDIA’. Might it be my Path? The project was originally created on Android Studio. But it was created on my mac and copied to Windows via a git repo.
